# Can not find channel named "" Expect Script

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I have two scripts I use in conjunction. This is because I have large amounts of commands that need to be sent to Routers/Switches, in large batches.

Full Disclosure I did not write these scripts, they were written by someone who no longer works with me, and I have very limited knowledge of expect.

The first script (Script A) is what allows me to execute a script on many devices at once from a central box, while outputting the results of the script to a file.

```
#!/bin/bash

let j=0;
let sleeptime=20;
let numberInstance=20;
if [ $# -lt "3" ]
then
    echo "Missing Parameters:"
    echo "start <script-name> <output-directory> <sites-file>"
    exit 1
fi


for s in `cat ${3}`
do

        echo Processing: $s on `date`;
        ./$1 ${s}${4}  > ./$2/${s}-${4} &
        let j+=1;


if [ `expr $j % $numberInstance` -eq 0 ]
        then
echo sleeping for ${sleeptime} seconds...sites processed: $j;
                sleep $sleeptime;
fi
done
```

The second script (Script B) is an expect script that spawns and SSH session to a device and sends a list of commands to the device.

This works just fine but in cases where it cannot reach the device Script A returns an error from Script B:

```
$ ./start_sw_FAST LH108_S2 Results/LH108_S2 inputlist   
Processing: Site1 on Thu Mar 19 14:31:07 EDT 2020
Processing: Site2 on Thu Mar 19 14:31:07 EDT 2020
Processing: Site3 on Thu Mar 19 14:31:07 EDT 2020
Processing: Site4 on Thu Mar 19 14:31:07 EDT 2020
$ can not find channel named ""
    while executing
"send "edit\r""
    (file "./LH108_S2" line 69)
can not find channel named ""
    while executing
"send "edit\r""
    (file "./LH108_S2" line 69)
can not find channel named ""
    while executing
"send "edit\r""
    (file "./LH108_S2" line 69)
```

In this case I know that these locations will fail. But when I am running this on hundreds at a time, i'd like for the prompt to be able to say something like:

```
Failed to execute script on Site1.
Failed to execute script on Site2.
Failed to execute script on Site3.
Failed to execute script on Site4.
```

I'm not sure how I can make Script A aware of Script B's failures.

Expect Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

proc _jgetRouterIPs {} {
set file [open router-list r]
  while {![eof $file]} {
               set buff [read $file ]
              }
close $file
return $buff
}

proc ssh2rtr { rtr usr pwd } {
 spawn ssh -l $usr $rtr;
set sess_id $spawn_id;
set ppret [ processPrompts $rtr $usr $pwd $sess_id 0 ];
if { $ppret == 0 } {
return $spawn_id;
else { return -1;}
}}


proc processPrompts { rtr usr pwd sess_id status } {
      set timeout 666;
      set spawn_id $sess_id;
      set fw_prompt  {\nuser@[0-9]{4}\-[A-Z]{2}-S2[>|#]{1}};
      set fwprompt1  {user@[0-9]{4}-[A-Z]{2}-S2\%\s};

if { $status < 2 } {
      expect {
      -re $fw_prompt { return 0;}
      -re $fwprompt1 {send "cli\r"; return 0;}

      "no)?" {  send "yes\r";
       processPrompts $rtr $usr $pwd $sess_id 0;
        }


      "assword:" {
                send "${pwd}\r";
       if { $status} { return 1;}
       processPrompts $rtr $usr $pwd $sess_id 1;

        }

     timeout     { send_user "\nTimeout on SSH!!!\n"; return 8; } ;#no response from telnet/ssh
     default     { send_user "\nSSH Unknown Error!!!\n"; return 9;  } ;#unknown error has occurred.
} ;#end expect 
} ;#end if
}



set site [lindex $argv 0];
set sw1 "${site}s1";
set sw2 "${site}s2";
set fw "${site}fw1";
set fw_prompt  {\nuser@[0-9]{4}\-[A-Z]{2}-S2[>#]{1}};
set fw_prompt1  {user@[0-9]{4}-[A-Z]{2}-S2%\s};

set sshret  [ ssh2rtr $sw2 user NotMyPassword ]
if { $sshret != -1 } {
                set spawn_id $sshret;
} else {
                send_user "Error Connecting...!!!";
}
        set timeout 666;


send "edit\r";
expect -re $fw_prompt;
send "rollback\r";
expect -re $fw_prompt;
*more commands will go here*
```

Comment: You'll really help yourself in the long run by developing good coding hygiene: proper indentation is crucial for readable code.

Comment: I'd also recommend you paste your bash code into https://www.shellcheck.net/ -- there are lots of improvements to be made there.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 0):

this is a common WTF with expect, when you use `spawn` in a proc. Note one of the caveats in the expect man page:

> Expect takes a rather liberal view of scoping. In particular, variables read by commands specific to the Expect program will be sought first from the local scope, and if not found, in the global scope. For example, this obviates the need to place "global timeout" in every procedure you write that uses expect. On the other hand, variables written are always in the local scope (unless a "global" command has been issued). The most common problem this causes is when spawn is executed in a procedure. Outside the procedure, spawn_id no longer exists, so the spawned process is no longer accessible simply because of scoping. ***Add a "*`global spawn_id`*" to such a procedure.***

Comment: Thank you for your input. I did cleanup the bash with the spellchecker. However my issue is not that the code doesn't work, it does, just fine. I am simply trying to find an attractive way to display to the terminal that the end device is unreachable. That is the only time it fails, and for obvious reasons it should.